# Changing DataFrame column names also changes column type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I'm trying to change the names of the columns. Before I change the names, the columns are Series (as it should be), but after I change the names, they become DataFrames, and thus cannot be grouped, etc. The line of code that's giving me problems is:

```
df.rename(columns = varDict, inplace = True)
```

I have verified:

- The same thing happens no matter how I rename; e.g., rename_axis, replacing with a list, etc.
- df is a DataFrame both before and after the renaming.
- varDict is a well-formed dict (as are my other dicts), and does in fact successfully change the names of the columns.
- The columns are Series before the renaming, and DataFrames afterwards.
- I cannot replicate this in a toy example, unfortunately.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I'm using python 2.7.5 and pandas 0.12.0 on Mac OS X. Thanks in advance. The full code is below.

```
import pandas as pd

def FileToDict(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        l = [line[:-1] for line in f]
    return {x.partition(',')[0]:x.partition(',')[2] for x in l}

#---Preparing the dataset---

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('movieDataset.csv')
df = df.set_index(u'row')

#These dictionaries incorporate information for other files
varDict = FileToDict('varNum-to-varName.csv')
titleDict = FileToDict('titleNum-to-titleName.csv')

#Changes the datafile numbers into movie titles
df.datafile = df.datafile.apply(lambda x: titleDict[str(x)])

#Changes the variable numbers into recognizable names
varDict['row'] = 'row'
varDict['datafile'] = 'MovieTitle'
df.rename(columns = lambda x: varDict[str(x)], inplace = True)

#----------------
#At this point the columns become DataFrames rather than Series
#----------------
```

Comment: pls show a complete example, it is impossible to just 'tell' from what you are giving. and include the pandas version. at the very least show ``df.info()`` and your rename dict

Comment: this might be a problem with duplicates (either in the df or in your rename). you can try assigning directly ``df.columns = new_columns``

Comment: How are the columns DataFrames? Could you show the output of type(df[col_name]) to demonstrate this.

Comment: Edited to include full code; sorry that I can't include the large csvs I'm building these from. 

type(df.datafile) gives <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> immediately before the renaming, and
type(df.MovieTitle) gives <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> immediately after.

Comment: @TimLewandowski thanks for editing, this could be a bug in pandas, but tbh it's not particularly useful without a toy example (although the full data would be ok too). Does it do this with just the first few rows `df.head()` ?

Comment: @AndyHayden Thanks again for the help. Due to your prodding, I isolated the problem to a particular column, which consists entirely of NaN in the 5% sample dataset I've been working with. I've confirmed the columns are persistently Series after I've dropped the offending column, so my immediate problem is solved. Any ideas as to whether this is due to my bungling or an actual problem with pandas?

Comment: @TimLewandowski I think you should make it an issue on pandas github, sounds interesting, potentially a bug, certainly strange: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues